# How to use unobtrusive javascript when you have parameters coming from back end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hava an anchor that nowadays are coded like this:

```
<a id="link${parameter01}${parameter02}" href="#anchor${parameter03}" onclick="functionName('${parameter01}', '${parameter02}', '${parameter03}', this.id)" class="class-name"><i class="fa fa-barcode fa-3x"></i></a>
```

I know that I can do it in an unbstrusive way by using jQuery with something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#class-name').on('click', function() {
        // Code from functionNameHere.
    });
});
```

What I don't know is how to pass the parameters that I have in the obstrusive way. I thought about doing a form with `input`'s hidden but that was rejected because the HTML file would become a lot bigger since this is a list comming from the server.

Comment: You could assign `data-*` attributes to the anchor and then read them.

Comment: Put them as data attributes on the element. For example, `<a data-example="Hello world">Test</a>` , and then in jQuery `$("a").click(function() { console.log($(this).data("example")); })` - [JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/og1Lvqr8/)

Comment: My advise is that you should embrace some data-binding library.

Comment: @CollinD, Since I have three parameters I would have to code three data-*? Wouldn't that make my HTML invalid?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, could you post an answer and explain it, possibly with examples?

Comment: @Santi, using custom attributes in HTML doesn't get my HTML invalid?

Comment: HTML5 explicitly allows attributes that begin with `data` ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)). Consider [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/og1Lvqr8/1/).

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi You can use attributes such as `data-param1="..." data-pram2="..." data-param3="..."` (please name them better than this)

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Sadly this wouldn't fit StackOverflow rules... I mean that you should learn some modern framework on which model and UI are separate concepts, so it's easier to work with parameters (and many other things)

Comment: @Santi, thanks for the explanation and link. I'll try `data-json` as suggested in a comment answer.

Comment: @CollinD I'll try `data-json` as suggested in a comment answer.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, you mean something like anuglar.js or that new framework developed by Microsoft? Unfortunatelly this a project that is already in production. I'm not allowed even to upgrade jQuery version.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Maybe maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an attribute on that element and access it with `this` in your event callback

```
<div id="foo" data-blah="blah"></div>

$('#foo').on('click', function() {
  const blah = this.getAttribute('data-blah'); // 'blah'
})
```

Comment: Since I have three parameters I would have to code three data-*? Wouldn't that make my HTML invalid?

Comment: you could do `data-blah="one|two|three"` and then use `.split('|')`, lots of ways to do that

Comment: @DanielLizik Why!? You can have as many `data-something` attributes as you want.

Comment: @CollinD you can even do `data-json='{"key": "val"}'` and parse that. or just reduce `.attributes`...same result

Comment: @CollinD Yes, that's true, though one with a split is most likely faster and more readable

Comment: I completely disagree. It's almost certainly slower (needing to split the string) and significantly less readable (subjective).

Comment: @DanielLizik, a JSON is what I actually need. What would be reduce `.attributes`?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi jQuery's `.data()` returns an *object* which should be more than sufficient for any JSON necessities. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/og1Lvqr8/2/). I still see avoiding multiple data elements as a slight reinvention of the wheel, personally.